# Compress bitmap before sending over network

Tags: c#, bitmap, compression

I'm trying to send a bitmap screenshot over network,  so I need to compress it before sending it. Is there a library or method for doing this?

Comment: look for "PNG" library for C#.

Answer (score 3):

When you save an Image to a stream, you *have* to select a format. Almost all bitmap formats (bmp, gif, jpg, png) use 1 or more forms of compression. So just select an appropriate format, and make make sure that sender and receiver agree on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something to compress the image in quality, here it is-

```
    private Image GetCompressedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, long quality)
    {
        using (var mss = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
            ImageCodecInfo imageCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(o => o.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
            EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            parameters.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            bmp.Save(mss, imageCodec, parameters);
            return Image.FromStream(mss);
        }
    }
```

Use it -

```
var compressedBmp = GetCompressedBitmap(myBmp, 60L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [System.IO.DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: As of 2012 it's using System.IO.Compression

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use:

```
private Bitmap compressImage(Bitmap image) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);// 
        int options = 100;
        while ( baos.toByteArray().length / 1024>100) { // 
            baos.reset();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, options, baos);// 
            options -= 10;// 10
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream isBm = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());// 
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isBm, null, null);// 
        return bitmap;
    }
```